# CodeIgniter 3 pagination not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I've revisited CodeIgniter's pagination class.

I've viewed many tutorials online as the documentation lacks details.

So I copy pasted the tutorial and changed some relevant details to suit a random table I have.

Controller:

```
public function sample_pagination($offset = 0){
    $num_rows=$this->db->count_all("genre");
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'pages/sample_pagination/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $num_rows;
    $config['per_page'] = 5;
    $config['num_links'] = $num_rows;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['records']=$this->db->get('genre', $config['per_page'],$offset);// take record of the table
    $header = array('genre_Id','name'); // create table header
    $this->table->set_heading($header);// apply a heading with a header that was created
    $this->load->view('pages/sample',$data); // load content view with data taken from the users table
    }
```

The view:

```
<body>

<div id="container">
<h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter Pagination System!</h1>

<div id="body">



<?php echo $this->table->generate($records); ?>
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
</div>

<p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds</p>
</div>

</body>
```

It's working fine, the only problem i have is that, the database table genre i have has 14 entries and the results on the view vary depending on the per_page settings.

say for example above, i set the per_page to 5. It will show 5 rows per page of the pagination with 3 pagination links < 1 2 3 >

the problem is that the details only showed up to the 8th row of the table which had 14 rows and it repeated.

First page is

1 2 3 4 5

second page is

3 4 5 6 7

third page is

4 5 6 7 8

I'm referring to the genre_id at the above. My table genre has genre_id as PK and genre_name as a col. so it only has 2 columns.

Anyway, if i set the Per_page to 1, it shows all the table rows correctly from genre_id 1 to 14.

I'm confused how this is happening? I learn easily via doing it myself so i tried doing it by copying tutorials online so i can see how it works but im getting confused by this.

Comment: `sample_pagination` is the controller right? and you are passing the page number as an offset? that's not how you do it.

Comment: Its from a tutorial i found online.

http://www.w3programmers.com/making-simple-pagination-with-codeigniter-framework-and-bootstrap/

and the 'pages' is the controller whilst 'sample_pagination' is the method.

Comment: I think im beginning to understand why it shows that way. 

In codeigniter active records there's an offset/limit to the records you retrieve and the way this tutorial is using the offset must have messed with the db query?

like for example $this->db->get('table', 1);

will only retrieve 1 row.

i never connected the two because i didn't know if the offset was correct or wrong but seeing as it was a tutorial i just assumed it was correct.

Comment: I think so, I can't read the tutorial now, but I'm going to write in an answer with the code I use

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it:

```
class Example extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index($page = 1){
        // Select the table
        $this->db->from('table_name');

        // Total rows
        // NULL for the table name we already specified it
        // FALSE to not clear any filters if you used some before (e.g.: WHERE clause)
        $total_rows = $this->db->count_all_results(NULL, FALSE);

        // Load the pagination
        $config['base_url'] = base_url('example');
        $config['total_rows'] = $total_rows;
        $config['per_page'] = 1;
        $config['reuse_query_string'] = TRUE;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        // Prepare the limit to use with the query
        $limit = array(
                $config['per_page'],
                ($page - 1) * $config['per_page']
        );

        // Set the limit
        $this->db->limit($limit[0], $limit[1]);

        // NULL as we already specified the table before
        $query = $this->db->get(NULL);
        // Get the results
        $result = $query->result_array();

        // Create pagination links
        $pagination = $this->pagination->create_links();

        // Prepare data to pass it to the view page
        $view = array(
            'rows' => $result,
            'pagination' => $pagination
        );

        // Pass data to the view
        $this->load->view('page', $view):
    }
}
```

I think the tutorial you used is wrong, that's not how the offset works.

Documentation:

[`$this->db->from()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::from)

[`$this->db->count_all_results()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::count_all_results)

[`$this->db->limit()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::limit)

[`$this->db->get()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::get)

Comment: I don't understand some of your code, like the null part. What did you mean we already specified the table before?

Can you also add how do you pass your data to the view? and to display.

Comment: Here `$this->db->from('table_name');` at the line after declaring the `index()` function

Comment: The way you use query is new to me so i'm confused, i'm skimming the query builder class right now to see what those are.

Comment: @ChiefMakii I added documentation links to the used functions.

Comment: I can learn those but how do you send the data to the view?

do i use it like tihs? $data['records'] = $this->db->get(null);
$header = array('genre_Id','name'); 
  $this->table->set_heading($header);
  $this->load->view('pages/sample',$data);

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
function sample_pagination()
{
    $num_rows=$this->db->count_all("genre");
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'pages/sample_pagination/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $num_rows;
    $config['per_page'] = 5;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 2; # added - 
    $config['num_links'] = $num_rows;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;

    $data['records']=$this->db->get('genre', $config['per_page'],$page);

    /*No Tested below this*/
    $header = array('genre_Id','name');
    $this->table->set_heading($header);
    $this->load->view('pages/sample',$data);
}
```

Make sure page loads without `index.php` and segment is correct.

Comment: what is this line?

 $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;

Comment: that's how CI now pagination in which page

Answer (score 0):

I simply removed this: or set it to FALSE.

```
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
```

After reading the 2 answers i've come to understand what was messing with my pagination was the offset. Since i set use page numbers to true, everytime i click on the next page it sent the next page number as the value(2 for 2nd page) so the offset will be set to 2 therefore the second page started at the 3rd row.

Comment: Check in my question. I've already removed this. You're duplicating answer

Comment: your answer was way different in approach to mine so i couldn't follow it. 

I posted this answer as soon as i found the answer to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

In Controller file:

```
public function favourite()
{
  $this->load->library('pagination'); // load pagination library
  $limit_per_page = 5;
  $offset = ($this->input->get('offset')) ? $this->input->get('offset'):0 ;  // actually codeigniter return offset not page 
  $total_records = $this->users->count_favorites($id);
   if ($total_records > 0)
    {
      $data['favorites']=$this->users->favoritesProducts($id,$limit_per_page, $offset);
      $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'user/favourite';
        $config['total_rows'] = $total_records;
        $config['per_page'] = $limit_per_page;
        $config['enable_query_strings']=TRUE;
        $config['query_string_segment'] = 'offset';
        $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        // build paging links
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
       }
       $data['viewfile'] = 'user/favourite';
      $this->load->view('template', $data);

    }
```

In view favourite.php file simple display links variable Like

```
<?php
      if(isset($links)) {
     echo $links; 
    }
   ?>
```

In model File Users.php

```
       public function count_favorites($user_id){  
          $this->db->from('favorites f');   
         $this->db->where("user_id",$user_id);
        $this->db->order_by("f.id","DESC");
        $result=$this->db->count_all_results();
        return $result;      
       } 


      public function favoritesProducts($user_id,$limit=2, $start=0){
         $this->db->select('p.name,f.id,p.product_id,p.sku,p.small_image');    
        $this->db->from('favorites f'); 
        $this->db->join('products p', 'f.product_id=p.product_id');
        $this->db->where("f.user_id",$user_id);
        $this->db->order_by("f.id","DESC");
        //$this->db->where('site_id',SITE_ID);
           $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result=$query->result();
        return $result;
       }
```

and it's working perfect!
Url like :  http://localhost//user/favourite?offset=5